# Ionicons in place of radio / checkboxes - not visible in Firefox but working on other browsers

Tags: css

I have the following CSS to replace the std checkbox / radio buttons with ionicons:

```
/* CSS RADIO BUTTONS */
.checkbox-icon:hover,
.radio-icon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-icon:before,
.radio-icon:before {
  visibility: visible;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 13px !important;

}

.checkbox-icon.ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank:checked:before {
  content: "\f374";     // icon for selected
  font-size: 20px;
  color: @light-blue;
}

.radio-icon.ion-ios-circle-outline:checked:before {
  content: "\f120";     // icon for selected
  font-size: 20px;
  color: @light-blue;
}

input[type=checkbox].checkbox-icon.ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank,
input[type=radio].radio-icon.ion-ios-circle-outline {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.mobile-item-row {
  input[type=checkbox],
  input[type=radio] {
    margin: 0px 5px;
  }
}

.label-ion-input {
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
```

My HTML for a checkbox is:

```
<td class="icon-radio-checkbox">
    <input name="desktop-icon-radio-checkbox" id="dsk_7bc76bda-cfc7-4f86-b19c-0a7a4890cdf4" class="checkbox-icon ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank ion-fw" checked="" type="checkbox">
 </td>
```

This works perfectly in Chrome, IE and Safari on iPhone, but not in FireFox. What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` can be only used on element that have content. `Input` is an empty element. `div` is an element with content.

**Visual explain and illustrate**

```
<div>
 :before
 CONTENT
 :after
</div>

<input type="text"> <-- no content
```

`:before` and `:after` enclosing the content. Since 'input' element has no content so there is no spot where it should be inserted. Firefox gets it right.

> **Empty HTML Elements**
>
> HTML elements with no content are called empty
>   elements.
>
> `<br>` is an empty element without a closing tag (the `<br>` tag defines a
>   line break).
>
> Empty elements can be "closed" in the opening tag like this: `<br />`.
>
> HTML5 does not require empty elements to be closed. But if you want
>   stricter validation, or you need to make your document readable by XML
>   parsers, you should close all HTML elements.

My advice would be to use the label element and to combine this with the checkbox.

**Here an example:**

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display:none;
}
 
input[type=checkbox] + label
{
  background: #999;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
{
  background: #0080FF;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label>
```